# Scroll textview to a specific substring after typing it in a textfield/searchbar in swift

Tags: swift, scroll, textview, substring, searchbar

I am trying to have a smooth scroll to a specific substring in a textView and have this substring on top of the visible textview area, that can be animated or not. I have tried a lot of different solutions but the only one that I could make working is the one below:

```
func scrollToSubstring (substring:String) {
    let value = getFirstHighlightedWordPosition(word: substring)
    themeTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), animated: true) //first adjustment
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [self] in
        self.setCursorPosition(value: value)
        self.ScrollToCursorPosition() //second adjustment
    }
}

func ScrollToCursorPosition() {
    //coordinates of cursor
    if let cursorPosition = self.themeTextView.selectedTextRange?.start
    {
        print(self.themeTextView.selectedRange)
        let rect: CGRect = self.themeTextView.caretRect(for: cursorPosition)
        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.origin.y)
        //print("cursor position:",point)
        self.themeTextView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
    }
}
```

the problem is that it is not smooth because it makes 2 adjustments, and can only be animated. I am sure there must be a better way to make it working.

**What I have tried to improve this code without success:**

1. removing the first adjustment leads to some issues on longer textviews
2. if first adjustment's animation is set to false, nothing scrolls, but if it is set to true, then second adjustment's can be set to true or false (either the scroll occurs with/without animation).
3. removing dispatchQueue 0.5: the scroll is not working properly so I guess it needs a time delay (edit: I lowered 0.5 to 0.25, it's smoother and seems to work for values grater than 0.25)
4. point is giving different values if the code above is modified: I guess there is a problem between setCursorPosition and caretRect

I am calling scrolltosubstring from:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    scrollToSubstring (substring: searchText)
}
```

and sometimes after a show segue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with this only method:

```
func scrollToWord(word: String, animated: Bool = true, minCharacterLimit: Int = 3) {
    
    // Limit word lenght for search
    guard word.count >= minCharacterLimit else { return }
    
    // Getting needed ranges
    let range: NSRange = (yourTextView.text as NSString).range(of: word)
    let beginning: UITextPosition = yourTextView.beginningOfDocument
    
    guard let start: UITextPosition = yourTextView.position(from: beginning, offset: range.location),
          let end: UITextPosition = yourTextView.position(from: start, offset: range.length),
          let textRange: UITextRange = yourTextView.textRange(from: start, to: end) else { return }
    
    // Converting Range to Rect
    let rect: CGRect = yourTextView.firstRect(for: textRange)
    
    // Scrolling in text view
    self.yourTextView.setContentOffset(rect.origin, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answear but your method behave the same way as mine. it works for short textviews, but there are problems on longer ones still.